Grouping and ranking issue: based on table shown, script or stored procedure should return ranking based on provided rules
Using this table, a query or stored procedure should return rank for each row as shown in rank table content. Rules are provided below.



hearderid
iscacId
paymentAmt




1234
1162
1000


1234
1161
200


1234
1163
300


1221
1160
900


1221
1165
100


1220
1159
3000


1223
1178
4000


1250
1130
800



Using this table, I have to create the rank table based on following rules:

Rank calculated based on highest amount desc

Different Header ID - Different ISCACID = Consider it as Individual Record

Same Header ID - Different ISCACID = Consider it as Individual group of Records

Unique Header ID – Unique ISCACID = Consider it as Individual Record

if headerid is same but iscacId is different first give rank to this group based on amount





hearderid
iscacId
paymentAmt
Rank




1234
1162
1000
3


1234
1161
200
5


1234
1163
300
4


1221
1160
900
6


1221
1165
100
7


1220
1159
3000
2


1223
1178
4000
1


1250
1130
800
8



I tried this using below query but unable to achieve it.
WITH Ranked AS 
(
    SELECT
        headerId,
        iscacId ,
        paymentAmt ,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY headerId, iscacId  
                          ORDER BY paymentAmt DESC) AS Rank
    FROM
        header
)
SELECT
    headerId,
    iscacId ,
    paymentAmt 
FROM
    Ranked
WHERE
    Rank = 1
ORDER BY
    paymentAmt DESC;


Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results as table markdown.

What are asking here, exactly? You don't ask anything.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.v

@ThomA how can i share scenario then

DDL and DML? A markdown table?

sorry sir really iam not ware of that

If you can't ask a question, and you can't provide consumable sample data (and expected results), it makes it very difficult (impossible) for us answer your question, @developer .

I'm amazed you've been a member 13 years and never see table markdown used? Nor read the editing help https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

@DaleK iam using stackoverflow very rarely since years. i was not much active here. i make sure to know new rules here

@ThomA update post with same data as table, please check sir

Now we jsut need to a question to answer; you've still not asked anything, @developer .

@ThomA added what i  need to achieve

Not sure i got your spec, but this seems to generate the same answer so:
SELECT  *
,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY amtGroup DESC, HeaderId, paymentAmt DESC) AS ActualRank
FROM    (
    SELECT  *
    ,   MAX(paymentAmt) OVER(PARTITION BY HeaderID) amtGroup
    FROM    (
        VALUES  (1234, 1162, 1000, 3)
        ,   (1234, 1161, 200, 5)
        ,   (1234, 1163, 300, 4)
        ,   (1221, 1160, 900, 6)
        ,   (1221, 1165, 100, 7)
        ,   (1220, 1159, 3000, 2)
        ,   (1223, 1178, 4000, 1)
        ,   (1250, 1130, 800, 8)
    ) t (headerid,iscacId,paymentAmt,Rank)
) x

I assume every HeaderId is own group and calculate the maximum amount per such group. Then it's a simple row_number ordered by DESC amount, with HeaderId and individual payment amount as tiebreaker.

sir need small correction, result is display amount column as max amount instead of individual amount

Check paymentAmt and amtGroup columns, it displays the original amount and grouped one, so you have both :)

u r genius thanks sir
